# when download button is clicked download should happen at backend

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have a download botton..onclick of download button the download should happen at the backend and i should continue doing other tasks ..download should not break when i click on other button..is there a way in php to handle this.. if so what method can be used
i have tried with curl function

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8888/test/download_ipad.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

but instead of downloading it is printing whole of the file

Comment: Where should it download to?

Comment: a normal dowload when you click on download it has to download as xls file

Answer (score 0):

Create a new php file and provide link to that in the button href tag.

In php file, you need to set headers for pdf and file path, for example:

```
<?php 
     $filename = "filepath";
//header for the file type
header('Content-type: audio/mp3');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

?>